# question about manual partitioning for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-11, 23.04

I have both Windows 11 and Fedora on my HDD. I want to replace Fedora with Ubuntu 23.04 (ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso).
I have a 50GB ext4, `/` mount point and 500 MB vfat `/boot/efi` from a previous Fedora installation along with Windows drives and a 99MB vfat Windows Boot Manager as `dev/sda1`.
My problem is Ubuntu setup wants to change sda1.
I am worried that maybe Windows will get into trouble, because it is not possible to use the 500 MB `/boot/efi` drive that I made before for a new boot drive.

[image: ubuntu setup]

Comment: Your ISO choice as details now show uses the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`.  I've installed 23.04 a number of times without issue to installed windows systems, however my QA was largely with other installers (different ISOs of 23.04) thus I've not used it. As I stated in a prior comment, I've re-install into Fedora partition(s) without issue; replacing Fedora with Ubuntu & not had impact on other OSes in the past (I'd use the *Manual Partitioning/Something-Else* option & tell the installer what you want) without issue; just read what the installer will do before accepting (it's pretty clear).